# Polymers this.$$(selector) (querySelector) for elements inside template repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I am simply trying to get an element inside of a template repeat by it's custom attribute. Here is the code:

```
<dom-module id="order-customize-sauces">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="order-customize-sauces.css"/>
<template>
    <center>
        <div style="width:100%; height:80px;">
            <input class="customize-search" title="Filter The List By A Search Term" placeholder="Search List..." value="{{searchValue::input}}" type="text" on-keyup="filterSelections"></input>
            <iron-icon icon="search" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;"></iron-icon>
        </div>
        <div style="height:300px;width:100%;">
            <template id="saucesRepeat" is="dom-repeat" items="{{repeat}}" filter="{{filterSelections(searchValue)}}">
                <paper-button data-sauce$="{{item.code}}" class$="button-{{item.SELECTED}}" raised on-click="buttonClick">{{item.name}}</paper-button>
            </template>
        </div>
    </center>
<div style="margin-top:300px">&nbsp;</div>
</template>
<script src="order-customize-sauces.js"></script>
```

As you can see I have "data-sauce" attribute that I want to select by. So here is what I have tried with no luck:

Try1:

```
var repeaters = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-repeat"]')
  console.log(repeaters.querySelector("[data-sauce]"));
```

Try 2:

```
var items = Polymer.dom(this.$.saucesRepeat).node.__data__.items;
  console.log(this.$$("[data-sauce]"));
```

Try 3:

```
this.$$("[data-sauce]");
```

Am I going about this wrong? How can I select an element inside of a template repeat? Also I am not using JQuery so if this could be javascript or polymer specific that would be great!

***EDIT:***

I have added the full JS code to help with the debugging.

The main function where this is the question is in the "changeButtonColor" function. This is called after a series of functions but it all starts with the "passCurrentItem" function. Also this element is a child of another element which is calling this elements function like the following:

```
this.$.allSaucesOptions.passCurrentItem(mynewarray);
```

The "allSaucesOptions" is the id given to the "order-customize-sauces" element.

Full JS Code:

```
Polymer({
is:"order-customize-sauces",
behaviors: [
    Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
],
properties:{
    animationConfig: {
        value: function() {
            return {
                'entry':[
            {
              name:'fade-in-animation',
              node:this
            }],
                'exit':[
            {
              name:'fade-out-animation',
              node:this
            }]
            }
        }
    },
},
//--------------------------------------------------
ready:function(){
  this.repeat = [];
  this.currentItem = [];
  this.originalArray = [];
},
//--------------------------------------------------
passCurrentList:function(list){
  this.originalArray = list;
},
//--------------------------------------------------
passCurrentItem:function(array) {
  var i;
  this.currentItem.length = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      this.currentItem.push({name: array[i].name, code: array[i].code, price: array[i].price, SELECTED: array[i].SELECTED});
  }
  this.resetRepeatArray();              //everything above works!!
  this.updateArray();                 //update visually
},
//--------------------------------------------------
resetRepeatArray:function(){                      //testing working!!!!
  var i;
  for(i=0; i < this.originalArray.length; i++) {
      this.originalArray[i].SELECTED = 0;
  }
  this.repeat = this.originalArray;
},
//--------------------------------------------------
updateArray:function() {
  var i;
  //for(i =0; i < this.repeat.length; i++) {
      //this.repeat[i] = {name: this.repeat[i].name, code: this.repeat[i].code, price: this.repeat[i].price, SELECTED: this.repeat[i].SELECTED};
      //this.changeButtonColor(0,this.repeat[i].code);
  //}

  for(i = 0; i < this.currentItem.length; i++) {
      //index = this.repeat.map(function(d) { return d['code']; }).indexOf(this.currentItem[i].code);
      //this.set("repeat.index",{name: this.currentItem[i].name, code: this.currentItem[i].code, 
      //                        price: this.currentItem[i].price, SELECTED: this.currentItem[i].SELECTED});
      console.log("set color "+this.currentItem[i].name);
      this.changeButtonColor(this.currentItem[i].SELECTED,this.currentItem[i].code);  //this isn't working
  }
},
//--------------------------------------------------
changeButtonColor:function(number, id) {
  var defaultClassValues = " style-scope order-customize-sauces x-scope paper-button-0";
  var defaultClass ="button-";
  // var items = Polymer.dom(this.$.saucesRepeat).node.__data__.items;
  // console.log(this.$$("[data-sauce]"));
  // var repeaters = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-repeat"]')
  var element = this.$$("[data-sauce]"); 
  console.log(element);
  // for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //     if(items[i].code === id) {
  //         Polymer.dom(this.$.saucesRepeat).node.__data__.items[i].SELECTED = number;
  //     }
  // }
  // var element = this.getElementByAttributeValue("data-sauce",id);
  // if(element != null){
  //     element.className = defaultClass+number+defaultClassValues;
      // console.log(element.className);
  // }
},
//--------------------------------------------------
getElementByAttributeValue: function(attribute, value){
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
      if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) === value){
          // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
          matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
      }
  }
  return matchingElements[0];
},
//--------------------------------------------------
isNumber:function(selected, number) {
  selected = (selected == null)?0:selected;
  if(selected == number) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
},
//--------------------------------------------------
removeFromArray:function(itemName) {
  var index, i;
  for(i = 0; i < this.currentItem.length; i++) {
      if(this.currentItem[i].name == itemName || this.currentItem[i].code == itemName) {
          index = i;
          break;
      }
  }
  if(index > -1) {
      this.currentItem.splice(index, 1);
  }
},
//--------------------------------------------------
buttonClick:function(e){
  var item = e.model.__data__.item;
  item.SELECTED = this.setSelectedNumber(item.SELECTED);
  var number = item.SELECTED;

  if(number > 3) {//original item
      this.currentItem[0] = {name: item.name, code: item.code, price: item.price, SELECTED: 4};//change original item to new values
      if(this.currentItem[1] != null) {                        //is there another item selected?
         this.removeFromArray(this.currentItem[1].code);      //make original item the only thing in array
      }
  }
  else if(number < 4) {//not original item
      this.currentItem[0] = {name: this.currentItem[0].name, code: this.currentItem[0].code, price: this.currentItem[0].price, SELECTED: 4};//unselect original item -- don't remove from array
      if(this.currentItem[1] == null) {                        //is this the first time selecting a new item?
          this.currentItem.push({name: item.name, code: item.code, price: item.price, SELECTED: item.SELECTED});      //add item to a new slot in array
      }
      else{ 
          this.currentItem[1] = {name: item.name, code: item.code, price: item.price, SELECTED: item.SELECTED};    //Update array slot with new information
      }
  }
  this.updateArray();
},
//--------------------------------------------------
setSelectedNumber:function(number) {
  if(number < 8 && number > 3) {
    number += 1;
    if(number > 7) {
      number = 4;
    }
  }
  if(number < 4 || number == null) {
    number = (number == null)?0:number;
    number += 1;
    if(number > 3) {
      number = 0;
    }
  }
  return number;
},
//---------------------------------------------------
filterSelections:function(search) {
  this.resetSauceArray();
  this.changeButtonColor(this.currentItem[0].SELECTED, this.currentItem[0].code);
  if(this.currentItem[1] != null){
      this.changeButtonColor(this.currentItem[1].SELECTED, this.currentItem[1].code);
  }
  return function(item){
      var string;
      if (!search) return true;
      if (!item) return false;
          search = search.toUpperCase();
      if(item.name && ~item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(search)) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
  }
},
```

});

Comment: It is returning "null" for me :(

Comment: Have you checked the DOM if the elements are actually created with the `data-souce`  attribute?

Comment: Hum... i opened the developer tools and inspected the paper-button. I don't see the "data-sauce" attribute on that button so it doesn't appear to be. Do I have to do something else to make it be attached to the element?

Comment: Just changed the code around a little bit so that "data-sauce='Woot'" and that shows up so then I also replaced "item.name" with "item.code" and that shows up great it just hates me when I put item.code on data-sauce.

Comment: Maybe it returns `null` and then Polymer removes the attribute?

Comment: Also I tried to do "this.$$("[data-sauce]");" when "data-sauce='woot'" and it is still returning null for me...

Comment: Weird, I'd still expect this to work. Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: I made a mistake above. The "data-sauce" attribute is still present when "data-sauce$='{{item.code}}'" is set. I just missed it when I was looking for it before.

Comment: And the code and the HTML are part of the same Polymer element?

Comment: Yes. I have included the JS at the bottom: <script src="order-customize-sauces.js"></script> and that html file is included in the overall document.

Comment: Actually doesn't sound like they are both part of a element. `this.$$.` only works from inside a polymer element. Please add the full element code that allows to reproduce (time for bed now zzz).

Comment: I have added the rest of the code. Hopefully this will help you whenever you decide to look at it again or whomever else will take a peak at it.

Comment: I think you should create a simplified example that does just the `<template is="dom-repeate" ...> ` and a button that invokes a function which calls `console.log(this.$$('[data-sauce]'))` to see if this works. If it does, the issue is somewhere else, if not, then you know the problem lies somewhere else. I forgot to mention that `this.$$(...)` only returns one element. You might want to query all. In this case use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('[data-source]')`

Comment: Alright I will have to try that and see how it goes.